# Android Backstack Management

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity A which calls another activity B. Activity B 3 has tabs/fragments (F1,F2,F3). When activity B is called Fragment F1 is launched initially which has an list view. From Fragment F1, on list item click I call a DialogFragment D1. This dialog fragment refreshes the list in the fragment F1. Everything on backstack works fine till the Dialog Fragment is called. The issue is when the Fragment F1 is refreshed and back button is pressed it comes back to same fragment as DialogFragment is called from F1. So the sequence is

A->B->F1->DF(refresh Fragment)->F1

From dialog fragment I suppressed its entry to backstack through below code:

```
if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                    fragmentManager.popBackStack();
                }
```

Now the back press sequence from fragment is

F1->F1->B->A

where as I need

F1->B->A.

Fragment Code to call Dialog Fragment

```
ListId sKey = pData.getId();
AppSession sInstance = AppSession.getInstance();
sInstance.setsKey(sKey);
FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity) (getActivity());
FragmentManager fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
ConfirmDialogFragment cd = new ConfirmDialogFragment();
cd.show(fm, "Confirm Fragment");
```

I have tried many things and read related posts  but nothing seem to be working. I am not sure if I am missing some thing . Please advise.

Comment: plz post your F1 fragments code

Comment: Full Fragment code is too lengthy. I have edited my post to add code to call Dialog Fragment. Please let me know if more information is required. Thanks.

Comment: if you see 2 F1 in your backstack it probably means that you are not only refreshing the list, but you are actually creating a new fragment.
Try to get the correct instance of F1 and refresh the current listView. That way your fragment back stack won't be messed up.

Comment: @MarioLenci Thanks for this pointer. I guess I am creating a new fragment. Looking into this. Will let you know if I still see any issues.

Comment: @MarioLenci I am indeed creating new fragment but now stuck as in how to prevent this. From DF I am calling B which creates F1 again. Now not sure how to prevent B from creating new F1 when F1 already exists. I know i m bit late in replying but had serve issues so was unable to test.

Comment: use a TAG when you add F1 for the first time. Then whenever you have to open F1, first check if there already is one in the FragmentManager using findFragmentByTag( String tag ).